# Open Tumblr App from my app?

Tags: android, tumblr

I try open the Tumblr app from my android app, i want to use a intent to do this but, What is the intent to open the tumblr app form my app showming a specific user ?

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.tumblr");
startActivity(intent);
```

this solution assumes, that you have installed Tumblr app on your device. If you don't, then intent is null.

Comment: This open the app but not show a specific user/profile, i look for a code like this but for tumblr:  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/"+ Id))

Comment: To open specific Tumblr activity, with some specific data, Tumblr application must implement intent filters/actions for that. I think that it does not offer this functionality, but I didn't search for it. It is more like question for Tumblr developers.